# Query based on multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a data table with health premium rates that depend on age, gender, and zip code.  I want to create a query that gives me just the lowest price premium by a particular plan name/gender/zipcode combo.

Example, what's the lowest price rate?

```
   Zip           Gender      Age    Lowest_price_rate
   ======================================================
   10001           F         90            ?
   90210           M         65            ?
```

Comment: 1. You want to filter record with one of the three mentioned criteria or all? 2. Want to show all lowest prices against your criteria or only the min(lowest)?

Comment: Can you post the SQL queries you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your're using some form of SQL and that you have the rates in the table already.

Group the entries by whatever you want and select the minimum one.  The query might look something like this:

```
SELECT Zip,Gender,Age,MIN(rate) AS Lowest_price_rate FROM MyTable GROUP BY Gender,Age,Zip
```

Of course, you can put a standard `WHERE` clause in right after the `FROM MyTable` part if you want to look at only certain criteria.  That query is untested, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT MIN(Lowest_price_rate) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE plan_name ='' AND gender = '' AND Age = ''`

Use the above query with the necessary values. (Tablename and values for the fields)